# Azure AD: Edge Browser auto-login by using browser profile data

Tags: authentication, azure-active-directory, microsoft-edge, azure-ad-b2b

we're running a business app (.NET Core - Blazor server) that authenticates users with the help of Azure AD. Currently, users have to click a sign-in link - enter their credentials and then they're logged in.

However, the new Edge browser stores user information by using user profiles. Is there any way a user can automatically sign-in to the application with his user profile from the browser?
I know Google has this feature in GMail - it allows auto-login with the browser's user profile. But is this also possible for custom ASP.NET apps?

**Edit**: To be more precise, the auto-fill functionality is working correctly. I have no issues with that. It's not about auto-fill. I wonder if there's a way to completely automatically sign-in a user?

Comment: If you have stored the account and password in Edge profile, I think it will auto fill in the account and password next time you reach the site using the same profile. Have you tried to save the account and password? You can have a try and tell us the result.

Comment: Thanks @Sven and please verify the Edge browser settings to save auto password (https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/save-or-forget-passwords-in-microsoft-edge-b4beecb0-f2a8-1ca0-f26f-9ec247a3f336)

Comment: Thanks. The auto-fill is working correctly. However, I thought about there is some special functionality that automatically sign-ins the user accordingly - not only auto-fill.

Comment: As far as I know, there's no such feature in Edge now. I think you can't auto-login with Edge profile.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comment, you could not auto-login to the AAD protected ASP.NET app with Edge profile, at most you can just achieve the auto-fill.